# Element or attribute do not match QName production, xmlns:xs defined correctly

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate this xsd file, but the same error keeps popping up:
**Exception: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. 
false**

This is the xsd file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="student">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="rollno" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="standard" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="section" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="staff">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="staffid" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs: element name="persons">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="gender">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="M|F"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="address">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="doorno" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:choice>
<xs:element ref="student"/>
<xs:element ref="staff"/>
</xs:choice>        
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is the XML file for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<persons>

    <person>

        <name>Tom</name>

        <age>11</age>

        <gender>M</gender>

        <address>

            <doorno>27</doorno>

            <street>Tony's road, koramangala</street>

            <city>Bangalore</city>

            <state>Karnataka</state>

        </address>

        <student>

            <rollno>10</rollno>

            <standard>6</standard>

            <section>A</section>

        </student>  

    </person>

    <person>

        <name>Shiny</name>

        <age>12</age>

        <gender>F</gender>

        <address>

            <doorno>10</doorno>

            <street>Main Bazar, Madiwala</street>

            <city>Bangalore</city>

            <state>Karnataka</state>

        </address>

        <staff>

            <staffid>123</staffid>

            <subject>Maths</subject>

        </staff>

    </person>

</persons>
```

All the other questions I've seen mention errors with the xmlns:xs= line, but I think I've defined that correctly. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Which line numbers are indicated? Is this an error message about the XSD file or the attempt to use the XSD to validate the XML?  You've omitted a lot of necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xs: element name="persons">
```

to

```
<xs:element name="persons">
```

and then your XSD will be well-formed and will successfully validate your XML.